# Как программно ответить на звонок в Android 5.+

Tags: android

Столкнулся с проблемой в ответе на звонок в Android 5.+ из моего приложения. Есть какие либо идеи как программно можно ответить на звонок.

Для Android меньше 5 версии:

```
Intent buttonDown = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
        buttonDown.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT, new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK));
        context.sendOrderedBroadcast(buttonDown, "android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED");

        // froyo and beyond trigger on buttonUp instead of buttonDown
        Intent buttonUp = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
        buttonUp.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT, new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK));
        context.sendOrderedBroadcast(buttonUp, "android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED");
```

Отлично работает.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26924618/how-can-incoming-calls-be-answered-programmatically-in-android-5-0-lollipop

Comment: @metalurgus Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.